# Aggregating Data in MySQL in tmp Table

Tags: mysql

Here is the issue: I am calling a stored procedure `get_orders_for_route()` 1 to n times depending on how many routes are going to be delivered for a particular day.

Each time I call the route I want to put the delivery data in a separate table and then once all the routes are picked, call `get_sum_route_orders()` which will sum and group the data inserted into the table.

However I have tried using a temporary table but it doesn't seem to be available when I create it in one stored procedure and try to read it in another.

I have tried creating a regular table and deleting everything from it, inserting into it and then reading the data but it never seems to delete all the records before it starts inserting new ones and so the information is not reliable.

In my latest attempt below I want to select all orders that have been marked for delivery the `ord_for_delivery = 1`. Once I have them I want to change the `ord_for_delivery` back to 0  and return the orders that are going out.

However when I check the order_details table it doesn't set all the records back to 0, leaving some hangers on which then get added into the next batch.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpRouteOrders;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpRouteOrders AS
SELECT 
    beer.beer_short_name AS bName,
    inventory_type.it_name AS itName,
    SUM(order_details.ord_det_amt) AS amt
FROM order_details 
        INNER JOIN
    beer ON beer.beer_id = order_details.ord_det_beerid
        INNER JOIN
    inventory_type ON inventory_type.inventory_typeid = order_details.ord_det_typeid
WHERE
    order_details.active = 1 AND order_details.ord_for_delivery = 1
GROUP BY  beer.beer_short_name , inventory_type.it_name
ORDER BY beer.beer_short_name, inventory_type.sort_order;

UPDATE 
    order_details
SET
    ord_for_delivery = 0;

SELECT * FROM tmpRouteOrders;
```

I have also tried in a separate table `DELETE FROM table` but again it doesn't delete all the records, it leaves some hanging on.

I can't do it all in one SP as I don't know how many routes I am going to get so I don't know ahead of time what I am going to pass into the stored procedure.

Ideally I could pass in 2,3,5 and inside the stored procedure, it would translate to `WHERE route_id = 2 AND route_id = 3 AND route_id = 5` but it could be just 3, it could be 1,2,5,6 etc...

Can anyone help me with a solution to this?

One thing to note this is hosted by GoDaddy so I don't know if that makes any difference.

Cheers